# Same name cannot be in different input types

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, input

Helli , I have developed a form where i am making clone of a div by clicking add new button. This div has one input box and table. when i click on AddNew button a new div will create which is the clone of 1st div but my issuse is same cannot be entered in input boxes of these divs.I am not able to achieve this validation.

```js
$("#insert17").click(function(){
$(".copyFromHere:first").clone().appendTo(".individualMarksSection")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  
  
  
  <div class="portlet light portlet-fit box individual individualDepartmentSection"> 
   <input type="button" class="btn green individual" value="Add New+" id="insert17"></input>
 
                                <div class="copyFromHere portlet-body individual individualDepartmentSectionSub">
        <label class="label1 col-md-12 individual labelDepartmentName"> Enter Department Name </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control individual DepartmentName"></input>
                                 <table id="tableboth" class="arrSubjects table table-striped table-hover individual">
                                 
    <thead>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" disabled="true" name="EmpName">
            </td> 
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control salary allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="3" name="salary">
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added validation script in javascript and cloned item will be added after clearing the input values.
You can change the code however you want it to be.

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#insert17").click(function () {
            var cloned = $(".copyFromHere:first").clone();

            $(cloned).find(".EmpName:first").val("");
            $(cloned).find(".salary:first").val("");
            $(cloned).find(".DepartmentName:first").val("");


            cloned.insertAfter(".copyFromHere:last");
            checkDupes($(".EmpName"));
            checkDupes($(".salary"));
            checkDupes($(".DepartmentName"));
        });

        $(document).on('change', ".DepartmentName", function () {
            if (checkDupes($(".DepartmentName"))) {
                alert('DepartmentName should not be same');
            }
        });

        function checkDupes(itemArray) {
            var isdupe = false;
            for (var i = itemArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var value = itemArray[i].value;
                if (value == null || value == '' || value.trim().length == 0) {
                    itemArray[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                } else {
                    if (i > 0) {
                        for (var j = i - 1; j > -1 && i > 0; j--) {
                            if (value.trim().toLowerCase() == itemArray[j].value.trim().toLowerCase()) {
                                itemArray[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                                isdupe = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!isdupe) {
                            itemArray[i].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  
  
  
  <div class="portlet light portlet-fit box individual individualDepartmentSection" style="display:none"> 
   <input type="button" class="btn green individual" value="Add New+" id="insert17"></input>
 
                                <div class="copyFromHere portlet-body individual individualDepartmentSectionSub">
        <label class="label1 col-md-12 individual labelDepartmentName"> Enter Department Name </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control individual DepartmentName"></input>
                                 <table id="tableboth" class="arrSubjects table table-striped table-hover individual">
                                 
    <thead>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" disabled="true" name="EmpName">
            </td> 
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control salary allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="3" name="salary">
            </td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: This answere is not helpful. i am getting same departement name

Comment: @ArpitGupta I thought you only wanted to include Salary and EmployeeName, Now I updated the code to include all the three inputs including DepartmentName.

Comment: sir my question is input box enter department name can not be same. when i click addnew button then clone of input box and table will come but two or more than two input box's(Enter department name) value can not be same

Comment: You can call 'checkDupes($(".DepartmentName"));' method on DepartmentName Change
$(document).on('change', ".DepartmentName", function () {
                if (checkDupes($(".DepartmentName"))) {
                    alert('DepartmentName should not be same');
                }
            }); 
Is this is the requirement for all three inputs?

Comment: i am clue less, can you help by updating above fiddle ? it will be good favour

Comment: updated the code, do you want to check duplicates for only DepartmentNames?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137417/discussion-between-arpit-gupta-and-nikhilgoud).

Comment: sir the code is same like previous
i have entered Finance and finance in enter department but it is not showing error.

Comment: @ArpitGupta I'm getting the error 
Have you got the latest code
one thing, copy the whole script and then try, I updated the checkDupes function

Answer (score 1):

Just add square brackets at the end of `name="value[]"`

like:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" disabled="true" name="EmpName[]">
```

Like that you will have an array() of `empName` inputs.

If you use PHP on the server side you can use the square bracket syntax to convert form inputs into an array, so when you use `name="EmpName[]"` you will get an array when you do this:

```
$EmpName = $_POST['EmpName']; // Returns an array
print_r($EmpName); // Shows you all the values in the array
```

Like so you can add as many input elements with the same name as you like.

Comment: hum.. Op's using javascript/jquery

Comment: @Weedoze웃 well but he will send the form somewhere to a server so PHP is just to give an example. The main thing is to use the square brackets like  `name="value[]"` which will work with javascript/jquery actually it's just the right use of HTML

Comment: it will be great if you can provide me a working fiddle. Thanx